# Delphi 6 / 7 Access Violation on TImage design time load

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm trying to load a jpg file which is 604KB big into a TImage component on a vanilla TForm but the load causes it to fail with an access violation:

Access violation at address 402372AD in module vcljpg60.bpl.  Write of address 0904000

I just tried it in Delphi 7 and the same is true except the vcl is 70 instead of 60 and the address is slightly different

Does anyone know of a bug in Delphi around jpg files?

Many thanks for any input on this
cheers
Colin

Comment: If I'm not wrong, JPG is exploded as bitmap before beeing loaded into TImage: do you have enough memory? Did you reference JPEGxxx class (I don't remeber corrent name) to use JPG files?

Comment: please can you read the faq and learn how to accept answers

Comment: Are you sure the JPG itself is not corrupted? Try opening it with Paint and saving it again (make sure you change something).

Comment: @David, "TImage design time load" probably means he's clicking on the `...` button in Object Inspector and selecting a JPG file to load.

Comment: @Cosmin Yes, I missed "design time"

Comment: Did yo apply available update packs?

Comment: I changed the jpg to a png which is far bigger in size but it worked fine

Comment: Sorry for the apparent confusion over how I was going about loading the jpg.  I was clicking on the ellipsis of Picture, clicking load to browse for it and then ok.

Comment: Unlike the answers to my other questions, on this one I don't see the large tick on the left...

Comment: It's not in the Delphi bug list, which goes up to Delphi 6, so it maybe related to the specific JPG file, does it do that with every file?. As a workaround *(Caption obvious to the resue)*. Open the file in MSPaint and save it as BMP (I know... file size...)

Comment: Does your file use jpeg 2000? If it does, then you probably need an extra library to decompress your image before setting it in your TImage component.

Answer (score 4):

maybe you problem is due to the colorspace of your JPEG file. Delphi has issues displaying JPEG images that have been encoded using `CMYK` instead of `RGB`encoding.

Check this [`Enhanced JPEG implementation`](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/19723) which fix the problem with the `CMYK` colorspace. also you can check this similar question [`Problem with showing some JPG files in Delphi`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319129/problem-with-showing-some-jpg-files-in-delphi/1321420#1321420).